# How to integrate NEMA x-15-P into mechanical/electrical design

Tags: ac, mains

What are some ways (or what is the typical way) that a wall mount device mechanically and electrically attaches the AC blades/plug into a design?  I've worked with panel mount IEC320 and cabled power entry in the past, but I'm curious what the common means of using NEMA plugs is.  I'm thinking of something like the ubiquitous AC-to-USB power converters that are everywhere.  Are the prongs molded into the plastic and then wire attached to PCB holes/pads?  Do they direct solder the prongs to the PCB?  What about in the case of foldable plugs?

Fixed prongs example
[image: iPhone AC-to-USB charger]

Foldable prongs example
[image: AC-to-USB w/ foldable prongs]

Comment: Your questions are confusing. Are you asking about 'locking' type power plugs? Also the term 'NEMA' covers a lot of territory. Could you be more specific as to the way your using the term. I have seen AC to USB converters use both wires or direct solder to PCB. It is up to the manufacture.

Comment: As stated in the title, I'm interested in NEMA x-15-P.  Specifically, the 2-prong 1-15-P and the 3-prong 5-15-P.  I'll find a picture of what I'm referring to and edit the question.